# Make a scrollable page without OpenGL

Tags: android

I want to design some view like that in the following image

http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/reviews/139419-image/Sony-Xperia-M-Review-019-UI.jpg

especially the rotating pages at the top. But i don't want to use openGL for that. Help me i am trying for getting this. I want something similar to that. Sorry for the bad english. Thanks in advance. I want the pages in the left and right to visible in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

For paging effect, you should be familiar with `ViewPager`. To get multiple pages visible at once, you should override the `getPageWidth` method of assigned `PagerAdapter`, which should return for example 0.75f to have 75% of normal page size.

To have a custom animation for moving pages you have to implement a custom `ViewPager.PageTransformer` which is available also in support library.